# Spring security logout handeler endpoint can't be accessed from frontend because of CORS

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, access-token

I have configured CORS and security filters as shown bellow, but for some reason I get a cors error when I try to log out from my frontend (localhost:4200). What could be the problem? I'm using java 17, spring boot 3.0.5 and Angular 15.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final WebConfigPropertiesProvider propertiesProvider;
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(@Nonnull CorsRegistry registry) {

        registry.addMapping(propertiesProvider.getConfig().mapping())
                .allowedOriginPatterns(propertiesProvider.getConfig().allowedCorsOrigins())
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "HEAD", "PATCH", "OPTIONS")
                .allowCredentials(true);
    }
}
```

property values are taken from application.properties and loaded correctly (all other endpoints work)

```
spring.security.web.config.allowed-cors-origins=http://localhost*
spring.security.web.config.mapping=/**
```

Security filter chain

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
class SecurityConfig {

    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;

    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    private final LogoutService logoutService;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/auth/api/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().
                and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)).and()
                .logout().logoutUrl("/auth/api/logout").addLogoutHandler(logoutService)
                .logoutSuccessHandler((request, response, authentication) -> SecurityContextHolder.clearContext());

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Logout service that handles logout operations

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class LogoutService implements LogoutHandler {

    private final TokenRepository tokenRepository;

    @Override
    public void logout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) {
        final var authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        final String jwt;
        if (authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return;
        }
        jwt = authHeader.substring(7);
        tokenRepository.findByToken(jwt).
                ifPresent(storedToken -> tokenRepository.deleteTokenByToken(storedToken.getToken()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your request and your response with headers.

Comment: BTW: This `spring.security.web.config.allowed-cors-origins=http://localhost*` shouldn't work at all. Xou can't  use wildcards in origins.